# Jquery , get position().right of an element?

Tags: jquery, position

So I am working on having a draggable image.

very simply, When you drag the image to the left or right side at a specific position, I want the image to snap back to the left or right side.

In the fiddle below, I have the functionality for the left side..but Im not quite sure what the best approach is for determining the right side since Jquery only allows top and left properties.

consider this code:

```
$(function() {
$(".headerimage").css('cursor', 's-resize');
var y1 = $('.picturecontainer').height();
var y2 = $('.headerimage').height();
$(".headerimage").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left >= 200) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        //####
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nk7wc/)

Comment: you can get the left and then add the width of the element to it to get the right

Comment: That's still relative to the left side.  The "right" would be the parent's width - the child left - the child width [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW62M/)

Comment: Try `ui.position + ui.helper.outerWidth()`

Comment: I'll experiment with this in a  bit. Havent used the outerWidth() method yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
drag: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.position.left >= 200 || ui.position.left <= -300) {
               ui.position.left = 0;
       }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nk7wc/10/

```
$(function() {
     $(".headerimage").css('cursor', 's-resize');
     var y1 = $('.picturecontainer').height();
     var y2 = $('.headerimage').height();
     $(".headerimage").draggable({
          scroll: false,
          drag: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.position.left >= 200 || ui.position.left <= -300) {
                      ui.position.left = 0;
                }
          },
          stop: function(event, ui) {
              //####
          }
     });
});
```

checking against negative value of position.left

Comment: ahh nice, didn't even think of that. Great answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To get the position to the right of an element I use this jQuery:

```
var target = $("selector");
var result = target.position().left + target.width();
```

Make sure the element is fully rendered when you are getting this value. Otherwise the results could be off.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one:

```
var rightOffset = $('.parent').width() - ( $(target).position().left +  $(target).width() )
```

note: I believe that this shoudn't work if you have margins and border around target element, not sure if that could be fixed with box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 0):

to get position *right=0*. Set *left = leftposition* without margin css is set

```
var leftposition = $(parent).width()-$(child).width();
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Right = function() 
    {
        return this.parent().outerWidth() - this.position().left + this.outerWidth();
    };
 })(jQuery);
```

To use it:

```
$("selector").Right();
```

Answer (score -2):

Do position left + width.

```
$(ui).position().left + $(ui).width();
```

Comment: mhh not sure thats going to work.  Thats still the left portion of the element, no?

Comment: I was actually trying to use width() yesterday to sort of subtract the remaining width from the position but i was falling flat, thanks though

Comment: You can use position + width to get the right side i was to hasty in answering the question here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/bMLBc/